# is not a valid installed package in R

Tags: r

I'm a beginner with R (2 weeks at it), and am having a problem with something that should be simple: creating a package.

Just to get up and running, I've created a simple function:

```
square <- function(number)
{
answer <- number * number
return(answer)
}
```

Then I've set my working directory to where all of my other R packages are installed

```
setwd("/usr/local/lib/R/site-library")
```

Then I create a package

```
package.skeleton(list = c("square"), name = "sbpackage01")
```

All files show up as expected in the new 'sbpackage01' directory, but when I open RCommander and try to use the package with

```
library(sbpackage01)
```

it tells me

```
'sbpackage01' is not a valid installed package
```

Any suggestions on what I'm missing? The next step in the tutorials I've seen is to compress then install it, but isn't the package installed by just doing 'package.skeleton...'?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you may also want to consider working through `RStudio` and the `devtools` package, which provide additional package-creation help/infrastructure (nothing you *can't* do in base R, but these tools try to make it easier)

Comment: Check My Answer from the given link as i have resolved this issue

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176970/failed-with-error-operator-is-not-a-valid-installed-package/55243157#55243157

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> something that should be simple: creating a package.

Haha. Well, no, creating a package in R isn’t quite simple (compared to module systems in other languages). You’re on the right track but before you can use your package you need to *install* it (or use [`devtools`](https://github.com/hadley/devtools) to install and load it dynamically).

The command `package.skeleton` actually creates a file `Read-and-delete-me` in your package directory which contains a short explanation of how to do this. Very briefly, you need to run the following command on the command line, from the parent directory of your package directory:

```
R CMD build packagename
R CMD INSTALL packagename
```

This is just a very brief explanation. Be sure to read one of the more detailed explanations, such as Friedrich Leisch’s [Creating R Packages: A Tutorial](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Leisch-CreatingPackages.pdf) [PDF].

Comment: In all fairness, RStudio and devtools really have made making packages _a lot_ simpler (if you decide to use those tools), particularly for beginners.

Comment: @joran True. My first paragraph is in reference to systems like e.g. Python where creating a module is as easy as creating a file `x.py` and then using it via `import x`.

Comment: @naught101 Thanks for your helpful and correct edit suggestion. Unfortunately some people didn’t review it properly and decided that it was invalid.