# Failed with error: ‘‘operator’ is not a valid installed package

Tags: c, r, rstudio

Currently I am having problems with loading an R package that I downloaded from github (https://github.com/hafen/operator). I downloaded the package and put it in my local R folder: "C:/..../Documents/R/win-library/3.2/operator".

However, I have not been able to load said package into R. I keep on receiving the following errors when trying to load the package. Can anyone help me. I found an error that I though was somewhat relevant that suggest updating "Rcpp" which I have already done with no success. Thank you in advance for any and all help!

I should add. I looked into this a bit more and realized the issue I am having is revolving around the C script that is contained within the package. If I remove the C script I can load the package, however, some of the package functions are dependent on the script and will not run as a result.

```
> require(operator)
Loading required package: operator
Failed with error:  ‘‘operator’ is not a valid installed package’
```

or

```
> devtools::load_all("C:/..../Documents/R/win-library/3.2/operator")
Loading operator
Re-compiling operator
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
"C:\Users\blakey1\Documents\R\win-library\3.2\operator"  \
--library="C:\Users\blakey1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpe611i9\devtools_install_499c5059149c" --no-R --no-data  \
--no-help --no-demo --no-inst --no-docs --no-exec --no-multiarch --no-test-load 

* installing *source* package 'operator' ...
** libs
Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="operator.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="loess_op.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'operator'
* removing 'C:/Users/blakey1/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpe611i9/devtools_install_499c5059149c/operator'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

Comment: you almost certainly need to install the [R tools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/installer.html). Once you've done that, you can `devtools::install_github("hafen/operator"); library("operator")`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42565317/error-installing-old-packages-in-r

Comment: install the R tools! link in my first comment

Comment: Sadly, I cannot download R tools and directly download from github due to specifc software/security restrictions.

Comment: Then you're stuck unless you can convince someone else to compile a binary version of the package for you. You could try to get it compiled on win-builder, but it might fail because of R version mismatches. If no-one else comes forward and I have time I can post that as an answer, but I think the odds are at best 50/50 that it will work. Basically, you need to (1) edit the DESCRIPTION file of the package so that it lists you as the maintainer (and gives your e-mail); (2) build the package & upload it via ftp to `win-builder.r-project.org` (see https://win-builder.r-project.org/) ...

Comment: (3) ask for it to be compiled/checked on "oldrelease" (R 3.4.4); (4) wait for an e-mail saying it has been built; (5) download the binary and hope it works on your system.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with RTextTools, as RTextTools is now not available on CRAN.

I have Download RTextTools From Given Link

https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RTextTools/

and copy 
RTextTools_1.4.2.tar.gz file in project root folder
then 
run this command in project folder in terminal
"R CMD INSTALL RTextTools_1.4.2.tar.gz"
 After running this command I receive below error
"ERROR: dependencies ‘SparseM’, ‘randomForest’, ‘tree’, ‘e1071’, ‘ipred’, ‘caTools’, ‘maxent’, ‘glmnet’, ‘tau’ are not available for package ‘RTextTools’"

Now install each dependencies from RStudio or RConsole (Any Editor used by you) by simply running this code

> install.packages("caTools")
>   Install all 9 required packages One By One (In My Case it was 9 Packages Dependencies required by RTextTools)
>   all packages will be installed except 'maxent'

Now download maxent from the given link
https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/maxent/

and copy maxent_1.3.3.1.tar file in project folder then
run this command in project folder in terminal
"R CMD INSTALL maxent_1.3.3.1.tar"

Now For RTextTools Run this command again in Terminal
"R CMD INSTALL RTextTools_1.4.2.tar.gz"

All is done Now..

But the Last Step is

Load the RTextTools using

> library(RTextTools)

You will see one more Error: **Load SparseM**
Now Loading SparseM use code below

> library(SparseM)

and in the last Load RTextTools

> library(RTextTools)