# Unable to load an R package when installed from a custom directory

Tags: r, devtools, install.packages

I already referred this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176970/failed-with-error-operator-is-not-a-valid-installed-package/55243157#55243157),[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795542/not-a-valid-installed-package-error-in-r-her-misc),

I am trying to install an R package called [Aphrodite](https://github.com/OHDSI/Aphrodite).

So, I downloaded the zip folder of R package from github and tried the below command

```
install.packages("C:/Users/test12/Downloads/Aphrodite.zip",repos=NULL,dependencies=TRUE,type="source")
```

The above command results in below message and moves the cursor to next line without any error message. Please note that all my packages goes into the below folder only.

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/test12/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
```

However, when I try to use the below command, I get an error as shown below

```
library(Aphrodite)
Error in library(Aphrodite) : 
  ‘Aphrodite’ is not a valid installed package
```

I also tried the below option but it doesn't display some of the folders which are available in the master directory. The details of it can be referred in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64311404/folder-in-github-is-missing-when-installed-as-r-package)

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("ohdsi/Aphrodite")  #APHRODITE is the package name
library(Aphrodite)
```

How can I load the package when it is installed from a custom directory? Why the package is not being recognized even though it is in the usual libpath folder?

Comment: Your R version is 3.6? Also, did you try to add full path to `library(..., lib.loc =...)` ?

Comment: No, I didn;t try `lib.loc`. However I tried `load_all` but that doesn't help either. And yes, am in R 3.6

Comment: It works. When the default lib.path is same as what I am defining in lib.loc, why do I have to declare them again? Any idea?

Comment: What is the output of `.libPaths()`?

Comment: It is `C:/Users/test12/Documents/R/win-library/3.6` and `C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.2/library`